Google Play keeps detecting collection of identifiers in child app, rejecting my Unity app
I have a children's application written in Unity. Recently, Google required updating the target API to 33. I updated it, and my app passed the review successfully. However, after some time, I received a notification stating that my app is using prohibited identifiers. The message stated:
"During review, we found that your app violates the Families Policy Requirements (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9893335#families-policy). We’ve identified that your app or an SDK in your app transmits identifier(s) that do not comply with our Families Policy. These identifiers may include, but are not limited to Android Advertising ID. For example, the destinations of Android Advertising ID transmission may include, but are not limited to [cdp.cloud.unity3d.com (http://cdp.cloud.unity3d.com/)]."
However, I do not send any information myself. There are no third-party SDKs in my project, and there are very few scripts. I have sent about 20 different builds with various modifications. Here is what I have tried, but it didn't help:
-Disabled Unity Analytics in the code and through the package manager.
-Updated to the latest LTS version of Unity (2022.3.37).
-Specified  in the manifest.
-Did not specify the above in the manifest.
-Built through Android Studio.
-Removed references to SystemInfo.
-Disabled everything except Purchasing in UnityConnectionSettings.
-Disabled sending editor analytics data in Unity settings.
Is there any further action I can take to resolve this issue?
Here is what I have tried, but it didn't help:
-Disabled Unity Analytics in the code and through the package manager.
-Updated to the latest LTS version of Unity (2022.3.37).
-Specified  in the manifest.
-Did not specify the above in the manifest.
-Built through Android Studio.
-Removed references to SystemInfo.
-Disabled everything except Purchasing in UnityConnectionSettings.
-Disabled sending editor analytics data in Unity settings.
-Is there any further action I can take to resolve this issue?
